# Remote debugging Java applets in Safari on OS X?

Tags: java, macos, safari, applet, remote-debugging

I have an applet that is problematic under Safari only (works everywhere else) and I need to debug it running in Safari.

The args to enable remote Java debugging are

```
-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=2502,server=y,suspend=n
```

However, `Java Preferences` on OS X doesn't allow you to set any args for the VM and I can't find anywhere else that might allow it.

Anyone know where JVM flags can be set for Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may depend on which version of OSX you're using.

In some versions, you should be able to do this using *Java Preferences* (in `/Applications/Utilities`). Either there's a *Java Applet Runtime Preferences* box directly visible in the *General* tab, or (depending on the version), after selecting a VM in the list (still in the *General* tab), clicking on *Options...* opens a dialog box for setting these parameters in *Applet Runtime Parameters*.

Alternatively, there is some documentation here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3210

Comment: Thanks! Did not notice that `Options` button when it was disabled.